# How to stop the matching of regex at one string with a certain pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the titles of some tables from plain text with regular expression in python.

The plain test was exported from some PDF files, which had a lot of `\n`s. I tried to stop the matching before the first appearance of the pattern `\n \n\n`, but the regex always returned me some more characters.

Here's an example.

The string was:

```py
contents = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nClient: ABC area: Location Mc\nHole: 33-44   \n \n\n \n\nKJK TechCen    Rep # 5243 \n \n\n \n\n95 \n\nTable 3.1:  Joined Liq L1 (P = 40 \n@ 12), Test With 2 % \n\noF \n \n\n PressRel V \n% \n\nLiq/To \n% \n\nLiq/Sat \nBu \n\nDenCom'
```

The regex I used was:

```py
re.findall(r'Table *\d.+:* *[a-zA-Z0-9 :&–=\n%@,()°-]+ [^ \n \n\n ]', contents)
```

I wanted the resulting string to start from `'Table XXX'` and end right before the first `' \n \n\n '`, like this:

```py
'Table 3.1:  Joined Liq L1 (P = 40 \n@ 12), Test With 2 % \n\noF '
```

But the actual string I got was:

```py
'Table 3.1:  Joined Liq L1 (P = 40 \n@ 12), Test With 2 % \n\noF \n \n\n PressRel V'
```

So how could I modify the regex to get rid of the annoying `'\n \n\n PressRel V'`?

Comment: Then use a lookahead, or a capturing group, `Table *\d.+:* *[a-zA-Z0-9 :&–=\n%@,()°-]+(?= \n \n\n )`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMlAy1/1), or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMlAy1/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a character class, you might use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert that what should follow is directly on the right.

```
Table *\d.+:* *[a-zA-Z0-9 :&–=\n%@,()°-]+(?= \n \n\n )
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/keukxy/1)

Or you could capture your values in a group and match the newlines following

```
(Table *\d.+:* *[a-zA-Z0-9 :&–=\n%@,()°-]+) \n \n\n
```

[Regex demo using a group](https://regex101.com/r/keukxy/2)

Answer (score 1):

You need a non-greedy `+?` instead of `+`, since all characters that appear in the end sequence are in the middle brackets.

```
end = r' \n \n\n '
result = re.findall(r'Table[^:]*:[a-zA-Z0-9 :&–=\n%@,()°-]+?' + end, contents)
#result = ['Table 3.1:  Joined Liq L1 (P = 40 \n@ 12), Test With 2 % \n\noF \n \n\n ']

# to chop off the end, if needed:
result = [x[:-len(end)] for x in result]
```

The `[^ \n \n\n ]` part in your example is equal to `[^ \n]`, "A character that is not a newline or a space"

Comment: This method also worked well. Thank you for the explanation of ```[^ \n \n\n ]```.